# Call methods of a std::is_empty type without an instance?

Tags: c++, metaprogramming

I am writing a template function, `foo()`, that takes a type `T` that is known to be empty (`T` has no members and `std::empty<T>::value` is true).

I want to call non-static member functions of this type without constructing any instances of it. Is this possible?

Here is some example code demonstrating what I am trying to do:

```
class Foo {
public:
   int func() { return 4;}
};

template<typename T>
void example() {
   // Call T::func() somehow without an instance of T?
}

int main() {    
   std::cout << example<Func>() << std::endl;    
}
```

Comment: Declare the function as static.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that any attempt to call a non-static member without providing a reference to an instance of that type is an UB. However, it's up to the compiler, it may be possible that for an empty plain type with no members you might get away with that, since nothing will access the missing-instance's actual pointer. I did it a few times on MSVC, and passed 0 as `this`, but I **do not** advise relying on that. Seriously. Going into that rabbit hole, next thing you may want will be `virtual` and polymorphism, and you'll get hit in the face with vtable/etc that magically needs `this` & boom.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl It can't be virtual as std::is_empty asserts no virtual functions

Comment: so, basicaly what Vlad said. Do it as a static, and then if you can write `example<Func>()`, then your `example<>` template can do `T::func()`

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I don't control Foo and can't change it to static.

Comment: Per standard you must actually have an object of the correct type to call the function on, otherwise you are going into undefined behavior territory. In the specific example it is however easily possible to obtain a temporary instance since we know the type to be default-constructible. As long as we know a usable constructor or we know that the class is implicit-lifetime we can create a temporary object to call on. Otherwise it is not possible without undefined behavior.

Comment: An example of how this could lead to UB: The empty class's constructor initializes some global state, the instance method uses that state, and the destructor uninitializes it. If you bypass the empty class's constructor and just call the method directly, it will crash trying to use the uninitialized global state.

Answer (score 1):

You've said

> I don't control foo and can't change it to static.

Sounds like a bummer, since if you want to call an instance method, you need an instance, so either you go into UB, or you need to conjure the instance.

Since that `T` you say is 'empty', can you afford a single global shared instance, just for the purpose of having an instance? Then you can create a shared instance as local static:

```
//+out of reach

class Foo {
public:
   int func() { return 4;}
};

class Bar {
public:
   int func() { return 456;}
};

//-out of reach

template<typename T>
int example() {
    static T shared_instance;
    return shared_instance.func();
}

int main() {
   std::cout << example<Foo>() << std::endl;
   std::cout << example<Bar>() << std::endl;
}
```

However, if that class is really 'empty', I don't see why are you worried about something as simple as

```
template<typename T>
int example() {
    T instance;
    return instance.func();
}
```

Of course I cannot 100% guarantee, but I bet that any decent compiler will completely optimize out that instance under your specified conditions. Of course you should check it after compiling if you really need to rely on that function to have as small stack footprint as possible.